# Why I'm not able to convert a file encoded in ANSI to UTF8?

Tags: c#, .net, file, encoding, utf-8

I've a text files, with text such as this:

```
025069;Zoppè di Cadore;BL;VEN;0437;32010;M189;271;http://www.comuni-italiani.it/025/069/
```

if I open with Notepad++, it says the encoding is ANSI. So, I'm trying to convert it and save in UTF8:

```
var ABSfilePath = Server.MapPath(UiUtils.GetPath + "/utility/listacomuni.txt");
var myString = File.ReadAllText(ABSfilePath);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(UiUtils.GetPath + "/utility/listacomuni2.txt"), myString);
```

but the result is:

```
025069;Zopp? di Cadore;BL;VEN;0437;32010;M189;271;http://www.comuni-italiani.it/025/069/
```

`Zoppè` now is `Zopp?`, and I've lost a char. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can convert it to UTF-8 in notepad if this is just a one off thing

Comment: Did it worked for you?

I'm having the same problem. I have a SQL database where i would like to extract imports/exports file in UTF-8 but some characters are not well displayed such as "é" that becomes ",".

I'm using Notepad+ and i would like to add these import/export files to Prestashop. 

I''ve tried several ways but still doesn't work. 

Can you guys help me please? Maybe it's possible to create something directly in the SQL but sadly i'm not an expert.

~Maxence Boudaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems seems to be when reading the file, try this:

```
var ABSfilePath = Server.MapPath(UiUtils.GetPath + "/utility/listacomuni.txt");
var myBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ABSfilePath);
var utf8Bytes byte[] = ASCIIEncoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, myBytes);
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(UiUtils.GetPath + "/utility/listacomuni2.txt"), utf8Bytes);
```

When you read the string using `File.ReadAllBytes`, it will load it as `UTF-8` already. With loading it as Byte-Array, we skip this part.

You also need to use `ASCIIEncoding.Convert` for converting the data.